# Converting recursive function to completely iterative function without using extra space

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, recursion, iteration

Is it possible to convert a recursive function like the one below to a completely iterative function?

```
def fact(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return
    for i in range(n):
        fact(n-1)
        doSomethingFunc()
```

It seems pretty easy to do given extra space like a stack or a queue, but I was wondering if we can do this in O(1) space complexity?

Note, we cannot do something like:

```
def fact(n):
    for i in range (factorial(n)):
        doSomethingFunc()
```

since it takes a non-constant amount of memory to store the result of `factorial(n)`.

Comment: Considering that function doesn't return anything, ever, I would say it's pretty easy to do.

Comment: I agree, with @Mark, waht is the output expectedd?

Comment: I am asking this question from a theoretical perspective. I'll edit the question a bit though.

Comment: it is still very unclear what the funtion should do. do something if the value of a number is smaller than 1?

Comment: The function is just calling doSomethingFunc a factorial number of times.

Comment: I guess you have the misunderstanding that the recursive function is O(1) which is wrong, just the allocated memory (like you said be it a stack or queue) is handled by the language interpreter.

Comment: @MaskedMan I know that recursion uses extra space, but a lot of the times recursive algorithms can be written iteratively without using extra space. I just wanted to ask if this is true in this instance as well.

Comment: Actually it does not call `doSomething` n! times. The number of calls is (for n starting 1): 0,2,9,40,205,... (Recursion: C(1)=0; C(n>1)=n * (C(n-1)+1). If you wanted to call it n! times, you should move the call to the `n == 1` case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, generally speaking no.
I mean, the space taken in the stack by recursive functions is not just an inconvenient of this programming style. It is the memory needed for the computation.

So, sure, for lot of algorithm, that space is unnecessary and could be spared. For a classical factorial for example

```py
def fact(n):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fact(n-1)
```

the stacking of all the n, n-1, n-2, ..., 1 arguments is not really necessary.
So, sure, you can find an implementation that get rid of it. But that is optimization (For example, in the specific case of terminal recursion. But I am pretty sure that you add that "doSomething" to make clear that you don't want to focus on that specific case).
You cannot assume in general that an algorithm that don't need all those values exist, recursive or iterative. Or else, that would be saying that all algorithm exist in a O(1) space complexity version.

Example: base representation of a positive integer

```py
def baseRepr(num, base):
    if num>=base:
        s=baseRepr(num//base, base)
    else:
        s=''
    return s+chr(48+num%base)
```

Not claiming it is optimal, or even well written.
But, the stacking of the arguments is needed. It is the way you implicitly store the digits that you compute in the reverse order.
An iterative function would also need some memory to store those digits, since you have to compute the last one first.

Well, I am pretty sure that for this simple example, you could find a way to compute from left to right, for example using a log computation to know in advance the number of digits or something. But that's not the point. Just imagine that there is no other algorithm known than the one computing digits from right to left. Then you need to store them. Either implicitly in the stack using recursion, or explicitly in allocated memory. So again, memory used in the stack is not just an inconvenience of recursion. It is the way recursive algorithm store things, that would be stored otherwise in iterative algorithm

Answer (score -1):

> Note, we cannot do something like:
>
> ```
> def fact(n):
>     for i in range (factorial(n)):
>         doSomethingFunc()
> ```
>
> since it takes a non-constant amount of memory to store the result of
> `factorial(n)`.

Yes.

> I was wondering if we can do this in O(1) space complexity?

So, no.